# I want to convert LR script to Jmeter script apart from Blazemeter?

Tags: jmeter

I don't want to use Blazemeter for script conversion so, i tried with proxy settings. I gave same proxy as " localhost" and port number is "9090" in LR and Jmeter and i have started recording in jmeter and at the same time replay the script in LR as well but script got failed at launch itself. ****Error is: SSL protocol error when attempting to connect with host "localhost".****

Answer (score 0):

If you're recording HTTPS traffic you need to "feed" JMeter's self-signed certificate to LoadRunner

[Create a new port mapping entry under](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/2021-2021_R1/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/UI/119200_ui_rec_opts_net_port.htm) Recording Options -> Mapping and Filtering and put JMeter certificate there

[image]

`ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` is a PEM certificate which can be used there.

More information:

- [How to Convert LoadRunner Tests to JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-loadrunner-tests-jmeter)
- [How to tackle SSL challenges during Load Runner recording](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-tackle-ssl-challenges-during-load-runner-recording-ajit-lal/)